# Flex Item only respecting margin or padding when both are set

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm currently exprimenting with CSS a bit, and I'm having an issue where a flexbox item is not respecting margin and padding correctly, and the only way to get a margin on the right side.

Here's the minimal reprodution I was able to come up with:

```html
<body>
    <div class="flexbox">
        <div class="elem">
            This is an element that does not have to be fullwidth.
        </div>
        <div class="elem" style="width: 100%;">
            This is an element that does not have to be fullwidth.
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

<style>
    .flexbox {
        padding: 2rem;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: flex-start;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    .elem {
        margin-top: 1rem;
        padding: 2rem;
        background-color: aqua;
    }

</style>
```

And here is the visual:
[image: Repro contents]

Please note the following:

- I have to use `width:100%`, as it is defined by the framework.
- Using `align-self:stretch` works fine, but I do not have a way to do this

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to write box-sizing for the elem class as well. Due to the dimension of the elements that include padding and maybe borders in future. Because box-sizing property allows us to include the padding and border in an element's total width and height. I hope it helped :)

Comment: Thanks! It works fine :)
Would it be possible to provide a corrected version, in order to help other devs?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed your problem by solving a couple of small problems:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.flexbox {
    padding: 2rem;
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: flex-start;
    gap: 10px;
}

.elem {
    padding: 2rem;
    width: 600px;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

Html stays the same, I only removed the `style=` in the element itself

Comment: As I said in my original post, I *need* to have the style in the element itself.

Comment: Well, than it does not make much difference, you just add style=“” in every div mile you did in you me example and between the quotes you place all the html attributes.